# Pulling artifacts by Android Maven plugin

Tags: android, maven, config, android-maven-plugin

I have a problem with android maven plugin.
I want pull artifact from device to my workspace. Wrote config in pom file

```
 <pull>
       <source>/sdcard/test</source>
       <destination>${basedir}/target</destination>
 </pull>
```

I dont hardcoded "/mnt", as i know, just sdcard mean that maven search sdcard where ever it mounted. And from emulator, and HTC Evo 4g, artifacts pulled successfuly, but with Samsung Galaxy S3, Galaxy Nexus, Nesus S, Galaxy Note. In log i see, that that folder does not exist on sdcard. How???

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.1-SNAPSHOT:pull (pullResults) on project test: Cannot execute goal: /mnt/sdcard/test does not exist on device. -> [Help 1]
```

If i type:

```
adb pull /sdcard/test /$mypath
```

every things are correct, I pulled that folder from any device. But maven cant do that.

start my profile with full debug, and see that issue depends on exception PullMojo.access$100, but i have all permissions to this dir, and parents dir. All msrked "l rwx rwx rwx"

Could you please help me. Thanks